# Sorting a MySQL query based on another query?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I'm building some very simple forum software as a sort of self-test for my PHP and MySQL skills, but I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this task. I have a table called `Threads` which contains a list of all threads. I also have a table called `Posts`, which contains all posts. Each table's primary key is an auto-increment ID. Each row in `Posts` also contains the ID of the thread it belongs to.

While I can easily retrieve all of the threads in a certain subforum with a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Threads WHERE ForumID='$forumid'
```

...I'm not sure how to sort that based on the latest post from each thread. I can get the posts for any given thread like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE ThreadID='$threadid'
```

...but I don't know how to incorporate that data into my initial query to sort it. Since each post has a unique ID, posts with higher IDs will always be more recent, so there's no need to compare dates or anything like that. I'm just unclear on how to actually do the query.

I'm pretty sure that this is possible in just MySQL, but if it's not, what would be the most efficient PHP solution? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the basic schema for `Threads` and `Posts` table, so that we can test the query too! I think it should work with a combination of columns in ORDER BY clause

Comment: A properly-designed join should do it, failing that you'll have to resort to subqueries. Either way, both are well documented.

Comment: See the third example in this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: @OzairKafray I can't do that since I don't actually have postID until I get the data from the Posts table. There is no postID in the Threads table.

Comment: @JakeKing - but there should be threadID in Posts table. So JOIN them like @odiszpac wrote down then `order by t.id, p.id`

Comment: @Jake King: Exactly as Joe has said in the above comment.

Comment: I tried that, and it works, but with one problem. The `ORDER BY` is applied first, then `DISTINCT` removes duplicates. However, it removes the duplicates from the *beginning*, not the end, and so it fails. Is there any way to reverse this behavior?

Comment: @Ozair Or am I doing this incorrectly? The problem is, I'm generating a list of entries which are correct, but after duplicate elimination with `DISTINCT`, the order is wrong.

Comment: @Jake King - I think your approach is right. In the column selection part of your query add max(postId) as maxpostid, then have your ORDER BY maxpostid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the given answers were very close, but I ended up using the following query:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM Threads t
INNER JOIN Posts p ON t.id = p.threadId
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY MAX(p.id) DESC
```

This is due to `DUPLICATE` causing problems due to its auto-grouping. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10905511/465378) for more info on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT p.*,t.*
FROM Threads t 
INNER JOIN Posts p ON t.id = p.ThreadID
ORDER BY
//whatever column you want like this p.date
p.date
DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Thomething like this can helps you

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.* FROM Posts p LEFT JOIN Threads t ON p.ThreadID = t.id ORDER BY p.last_modified_time DESC
```

Or

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.* FROM Posts p LEFT JOIN Threads t ON p.ThreadID = t.id ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

Comment: Very close, see my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

A simple JOIN statement is the solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM Threads t
JOIN Posts p ON t.ThreadID = p.ThreadID
ORDER BY t.ModificationDate DESC -- or whatever column you want
```

This gives you the latest posts over all threads.