# Does ORDER BY apply before or after DISTINCT?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

In a MySQL query, when using the `DISTINCT` option, does `ORDER BY` apply after the duplicates are removed? If not, is there any way to make it do so? I think it's causing some issues with my code.

**EDIT**:
Here's some more information about what's causing my problem. I understand that, at first glance, this order would not be important, since I am dealing with duplicate rows. However, this is not entirely the case, since I am using an `INNER JOIN` to sort the rows.

Say I have a table of forum threads, containing this data:

```
+----+--------+-------------+
| id | userid |    title    |
+----+--------+-------------+
|  1 |      1 | Information |
|  2 |      1 | FAQ         |
|  3 |      2 | Support     |
+----+--------+-------------+
```

I also have a set of posts in another table like this:

```
+----+----------+--------+---------+
| id | threadid | userid | content |
+----+----------+--------+---------+
|  1 |        1 |      1 | Lorem   |
|  2 |        1 |      2 | Ipsum   |
|  3 |        2 |      2 | Test    |
|  4 |        3 |      1 | Foo     |
|  5 |        2 |      3 | Bar     |
|  6 |        3 |      5 | Bob     |
|  7 |        1 |      2 | Joe     |
+----+----------+--------+---------+
```

I am using the following MySQL query to get all threads, then sort them based on the latest post (assuming that posts with higher ids are more recent:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM Threads t
INNER JOIN Posts p ON t.id = p.threadid
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

This works, and generates something like this:

```
+----+--------+-------------+
| id | userid |    title    |
+----+--------+-------------+
|  1 |      1 | Information |
|  3 |      2 | Support     |
|  2 |      1 | FAQ         |
|  3 |      2 | Support     |
|  2 |      1 | FAQ         |
|  1 |      1 | Information |
|  1 |      1 | Information |
+----+--------+-------------+
```

However, as you can see, the information is correct, but there are duplicate rows. I'd like to remove such duplicates, so I used `SELECT DISTINCT` instead. However, this yielded the following:

```
+----+--------+-------------+
| id | userid |    title    |
+----+--------+-------------+
|  3 |      2 | Support     |
|  2 |      1 | FAQ         |
|  1 |      1 | Information |
+----+--------+-------------+
```

This is obviously wrong, since the "Information" thread should be on top. It would seem that using `DISTINCT` causes the duplicates to be removed from the top to the bottom, so only the final rows are left. This causes some issues in the sorting.

Is this the case, or am I analyzing things incorrectly?

Comment: What issue do you think it's causing?  What difference would it make?

Comment: why would it matter? before or after applying distinct, the order should be the same

Comment: can you show us a sample query of what you are trying and the actual problem you are running into?

Comment: I believe the OP is referring to which row values are returned. For example, are the results sorted *after* `DISTINCT` sorted (and therefore an unsorted value within the `DISTINCT` could be presented) or before?

Comment: @bfrohs - Doesn't make any sense to me. You would get the same results if you sort the rows first then remove the duplicates as opposed to removing the duplicates first and then sorting what remains.

Comment: For example, if a row is grouped by `user`. User #1 has two `name` values: 'c' and 'a'. User #2 has one `name` value: 'b'. Sorted by `id` first (asc), the return would be (1:a;2:b;). However, if DISTINCT is run first, the return would be (1:c;2:b;).

Comment: @MartinSmith, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905026/does-order-by-apply-before-or-after-distinct#comment14218937_10905026

Comment: @bfrohs - Your link is back to this question! Is this some weird MySQL thing then? `ORDER BY` ought to specify the order of the results returned to the client. Does `DISTINCT` have some side effect in MySQL that would prevent that?

Comment: @bfrohs, but with DISTINCT you'd get (1:a;1:c;2:b).

Comment: @MartinSmith, it's back to the comment on the question--just wanted to make sure you were looking at the right one. And yes, I'm fairly confident the second example (DISTINCT is run first) is true.

Comment: @MarcusAdams, good call, I'm thinking of `GROUP BY` mixed with `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @eggyal Updated the question with a lot more information. Please see the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things to understand:

1. Generally speaking, resultsets are [unordered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10418282/623041) unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause; to the extent that you specify a [non-strict order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_order#Strict_total_order) (i.e. `ORDER BY` over non-unique columns), the order in which records that are equal under that ordering appear within the resultset is undefined.

   I suspect you may be specifying such a non-strict order, which is the root of your problems: ensure that your ordering is strict by specifying `ORDER BY` over a set of columns that is sufficient to uniquely identify each record for which you care about its final position in the resultset.
2. [`DISTINCT` may use `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/distinct-optimization.html), which causes the results to be ordered by the grouped columns; that is, `SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c FROM t` will produce a resultset that appears as though `ORDER BY a, b, c` has been applied.  Again, specifying a sufficiently strict order to meet your needs will override this effect.

---

Following your update, bearing in mind my point #2 above, it is clear that the effect of grouping the results to achieve `DISTINCT` makes it impossible to then order by the non-grouped column `p.id`; instead, you want:

```sql
SELECT   t.*
FROM     Threads t INNER JOIN Posts p ON t.id = p.threadid
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY MAX(p.id) DESC
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that works. So, just to confirm, `MAX()` compares using the max value of `p.id` in each group?

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` informs MySQL how to build a rowset for you, `ORDER BY` gives a hint how this rowset should by presented. So the answer is: `DISTINCT` first, `ORDER BY` last.

Comment: But, in reality, `DISTINCT` is implemented by sorting the results... so perhaps not if the optimiser uses the same ordering for both tasks.

Comment: In this case, as eggyval points out, there is an [exception](http://forge.mysql.com/w/images/a/ae/HowMySQLHandlesOrderGroupDistinct.pdf). When DISTINCT is grouped with ORDER BY, it does the sorting (filesort) first.

Answer (score 1):

The order in which `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` are applied, in most cases, will not affect the final output.

However, if you also use `GROUP BY`, this **will** affect the final output. In this case, the `ORDER BY` is performed *after* the `GROUP BY`, which will return unexpected results (assuming you expect the sort to be performed before the grouping).

Comment: [`DISTINCT` may use `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/distinct-optimization.html).  What would performing ordering *before* grouping accomplish that performing it afterwards doesn't (bearing in mind that selecting ungrouped columns without an aggregation function results in indeterminate results - not relevant in this case anyway as `DISTINCT` ensures no such columns exist)?

Comment: @eggyal, the issue isn't with `DISTINCT`, but with `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`. If rows are grouped, but not selected, `DISTINCT` doesn't help anything, and the query could return the "wrong" row values (e.g. an `id`, that is later used to retrieve values).

Answer (score 0):

in Mysql, **DISTINCT** runs first, and then **order by** runs on the data table selected by the **DISTINCT**.

for better understanding visit: [leetcode: Nth highest salary](https://leetcode.com/problems/nth-highest-salary/solutions/4030261/mysql-for-new-user-remove-hypen-from-every-line/)