# Yii2 : LeftJoin query with Where clause & orderBy clause

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have write query to get distinct stateID whose status is active, from tbl_summer table which is primary key of table tbl_states.

I want the listing of distinct state names in alphabetical order.
Actually i got this from following query but alphabetical order is not getting...

So what is the solution...?

**Here is my query :**

```
$query = Tbl_summer::find()
    ->select('tbl_summer.StateID, tbl_states.state_name')
    ->distinct('tbl_summer.StateID')
    ->from('tbl_summer')
    ->leftJoin('tbl_states', ['tbl_states.ID' => 'tbl_summer.StateID'])
    ->where(['tbl_summer.IsActive' => '1'])
    ->orderBy(['tbl_states.state_name' => SORT_ASC]);
```

Comment: You have to use group by instead of distinct. See this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10905511/57091

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
$query = Tbl_summer::find()
    ->select('tbl_summer.StateID, tbl_states.state_name')
    ->from('tbl_summer')
    ->leftJoin('tbl_states', ['tbl_states.ID' => 'tbl_summer.StateID'])
    ->where(['tbl_summer.IsActive' => '1'])
    ->groupBy('tbl_summer.StateID, tbl_states.state_name')
    ->orderBy(['tbl_states.state_name' => SORT_ASC]);
```

I think the second field in `groupBy` is not needed if there is only one name for one id.

Comment: @SantoshGaikwad What does that mean? Which problem do you get?